# Is it likely that an aircraft could have been near 10° 08' north at local midnight August 26/27, 2003?

Tags: aircraft-identification, altitude

**Edit: The astronomical data turned out to be different**. I'm keeping the constraints below as they where, but those are not relevant to finding the closest person to Mars.

<s>This is part of an effort to determine [which human has been closest to Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48100/8693). As Apollo astronauts and ISS space station crew are ruled out, this someone must have been on Earth</s>

**That's why I'm turning to you**. Planes are frequently flying 10km or higher, much higher than any mountain on Earth, and passengers and pilots are therefore higher up than any people on the ground.

There are some rather delicate restrictions:

- The aircraft must have been very close to 10° 08' north. There's a quickly growing altitude penalty for being far from this..
- The aircraft must have been at this latitude at local solar midnight
- The longitude is not overly important. For the western hemisphere, the date is August 26/27, for the Eastern hemisphere, it's August 27/28. Africa can be either, but has a 700m altitude penalty be default.

[image: 10° 08' on a map]

**Is night-time air traffic dense enough for this place to exist?**

From initial research, busy airports such as Singapore and Kuala Lumpur are south of this line

Comment: what kind of data/proof would you require to accept a yes or a no?

Comment: @Federico Some estimate of how many planes are actually flying in relevant routes would be enough. I have little hope for identifying a specific flight.

Comment: The southern tip of India and island of Sri Lanka virtually touch the line; as nearly as I can tell, the island of Formosa (Taiwan) is hidden under it, as is Hong Kong.

Comment: >Over 1 hour, it increased by 31 km.  From the other question. So for extra flight altitude to me meaningful, you need to look only 20 minutes around closest earth-mars approach. At what exact time was that? This will rule out 95% of place on earth

Comment: @Jeffrey The astronomical side of things have been updated beyond recovery for this question. I can't delete it as it already has an answer, but this question will not settle the original problem that motivated the post.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Taiwan and Hong Kong are around 22-25N nowhere near the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is very likely that an aircraft would be near that position/time/date as there are many aircraft that fly overnight flights from North American airports to and from South American airports, between Europe and Africa, and also between Asia and Australia.

For example, Air Canada has daily night fights from a Toronto, Canada to Santiago, Chile and both the outbound flight, and return flight, would often pass each other in that very same area and time. I would often operate those flights and we would chat with the crew of the opposite flight to exchange reports on flight conditions.

There are MANY other airlines with similar north-south routes operating overnight flights all over the world.

[image]

Comment: There are overnight flights between Europe and South Africa as well.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it illustrates the original problem of finding night time traffic over a latitude, which is likely somewhat reusable for other similar astronomical problems.